# PHP: if (!$val) VS if (empty($val)). Is there any difference?

Tags: php, null, if-statement, boolean

I was wondering what's the difference the two cases below, and which one is recommended?

```
$val = 0;

if (!$val) {
  //True
}

if (empty($val) {
  //It's also True
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Have a look at the [PHP type comparison table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

If you check the table, you'll notice that for all cases, `empty($x)` is the same as `!$x`. So it comes down to handling uninitialised variables. `!$x` creates an `E_NOTICE`, whereas `empty($x)` does not.

Comment: +1.  Also note that this is the same as `!= [boolean result of evaluating $val]`, so the last column of the first table is mostly what you should be looking at.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know. So I guess empty($x) is the safer approach. I assume the difference is negligible performance wise right?

Comment: Please note that when using empty() on inaccessible object properties, the __isset overloading method will be called, if declared.

Answer (score 8):

If you use empty and the variable was never set/created, no warning/error will be thrown.

Answer (score 4):

Let see:

[`empty` documentation:](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

> The following things are considered to be `empty`:
>
> - `""` (an empty string)
> - `0` (`0` as an integer)
> - `0.0` (`0` as a float)
> - `"0"` (`0` as a string)
> - `NULL`
> - `FALSE`
> - `array()` (an empty array)
> - `var $var;` (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)

[Booleans documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php):

> When converting to boolean, the following values are considered `FALSE`:
>
> - the boolean `FALSE` itself
> - the integer `0` (zero)
> - the float `0.0` (zero)
> - the empty string, and the string `"0"`
> - an array with zero elements
> - an object with zero member variables (PHP 4 only)
> - the special type `NULL` (including unset variables)
> - `SimpleXML` objects created from empty tags

It seems the only difference (regarding the resulting value) is how a `SimpleXML` instance is handled. Everything else seems to give the same result (if you invert the boolean cast of course).

Comment: So what's the conclusion? From the list, boolean seems like the more robust check...

Comment: This is incorrect. A quick test at the PHP shell reveals that `empty` handles empty `SimpleXMLElement` instances just like `!` does; it's simply an error in the `empty` documentation that they aren't mentioned there.

Comment: Gotta love the duplication of doc.